# Dynamically WebUserControl UpdatePanel with validators [ASP.NET]

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have this problem:
Add in UpdatePanel a TextBox with RequiredFieldValidator.
Then at the Postback add values to DB and redirect to an other Page.
My problem is why when I add one MyControl and click GO button, ValidationSummary don't stop the postback, and why at the second click the ValidationSummary fire?
The second problem is why VisualStudio don't find MyControl class(Underline it with red) but when I compile result is no error?

This is the code:

**Default.aspx**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test Validators</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <div>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upAdd" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="cmdAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" onclick="cmdAdd_Click" CausesValidation="false" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <hr />
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upValidators" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phValidators" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>                    
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="cmdAdd" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <hr />
            <asp:Button ID="cmdGo" runat="server" Text="Go" onclick="cmdGo_Click" />
        </div>
        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="valSum" HeaderText="Errors:" ShowSummary="False" ShowMessageBox="True" EnableClientScript="True" DisplayMode="BulletList" runat="server"></asp:ValidationSummary>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
    {
        base.LoadViewState(savedState);

        List<int> m_oItems = new List<int>();

        if (ViewState["ItemsAdded"] != null)
        {
            m_oItems = (List<int>)ViewState["ItemsAdded"];
        }

        ViewState["ItemsAdded"] = m_oItems;

        foreach (int m_oItem in m_oItems)
        {
            MyControl m_oMyControl = (MyControl)LoadControl("MyControl.ascx");

            phValidators.Controls.Add(m_oMyControl);
        }
    }

    protected void cmdAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<int> m_oItems = new List<int>();

        if (ViewState["ItemsAdded"] != null)
        {
            m_oItems = (List<int>)ViewState["ItemsAdded"];
        }

        m_oItems.Add(m_oItems.Count);

        ViewState["ItemsAdded"] = m_oItems;

        MyControl m_oMyControl = (MyControl)LoadControl("MyControl.ascx");

        phValidators.Controls.Add(m_oMyControl);
    }
    protected void cmdGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsValid)
            return;

        //Add To DB

        Response.Redirect("http://www.google.it/");
    }
}
```

**MyControl.ascx**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLanguage" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rqrLanguage" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Language not set" ControlToValidate="txtLanguage"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<br />
```

Thank you very much
Damiano